# How to find when record was last updated?

Tags: sql, hadoop, presto, trino

How to find when table rows were last updated/inserted? Presto is ANSI-SQL compliant so even if you don't know Presto, maybe there's a generic SQL way that would point me in the right direction.

I'm using Hadoop. Presto queries are quicker than Hive. "Describe" just gives column names.

https://prestosql.io/docs/current/

Answer (score 3):

[Presto 309](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-309.html) added a hidden `$properties` table in the Hive connector for each table that exposes the Hive table properties. You can use it to find the last update time (replace `example` with your table name):

```
SELECT transient_lastddltime FROM "example$properties"
```